# Can I use an object as a predicate for criteriaquery in JPA when some fields can be NULL?

Tags: java, rest, jpa, predicate, criteriaquery

I have an object, we will call it Person:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person extends PersistentObject {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private String age;

    @Column(name = "NICKNAME")
    private String nickname;

    @Column(name = "HAIR_COLOR")
        private String hairColor;
.
.
.
```

I want to use this object as a filter on a CriteriaQuery using predicates, but when some of the input Obj is NULL (for example, NickName) it breaks the query. Here is an example of the code I have at the moment.

```
public List<Person> getPeople(List<Person> peopleToGet) 
    {     
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Person> cq = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
        Root<Person> e = cq.from(Person.class);

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        for(Person person : peopleToGet)
        {
            predicates.add(cb.or(cb.and(
                    cb.equal(e.get("name"), person.getName()),
                    cb.equal(e.get("age"), person.getAge()),
                    cb.equal(e.get("nickname"), person.getNickname()),
                    cb.equal(e.get("hairColor"), person.getHairColor())
                    )));
.
.
.
```

Is it possible to use an object as a filter when the objects values are not always the same?

Example input: [{"name":"Bob","age":"30"},{"name":"William","nickname":"Bill"}]

In this example, I want to get every person in the PERSON table where:
the persons name is Bob AND the age is 30
OR the persons name is William AND the nickname is Bill

Sorry if this example is a little unclear, I have changed the code to make it as easy as possible to translate to other examples. My knowledge of JPA in general is basic, at best, being self taught (Read, Google) over the past few months. Any assistance with this would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: what is `representation` here?

Comment: @KalaiselvanA sorry, my fault. I hadnt changed all my original code. For confidentiality reasons, I changed the exact code and replaced my object with an example "Person" object. I have fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you are saying you want a criterion to be applied, if the relevant property of the bean is not `null` and *not to be applied*, if the property *is* `null`. For that you have to create a list and then transform to an array to give as argument to `and()` (just like you do with `List<Predicate> predicates`):

```
for( Person person : peopleToGet ) {
    List<Predicate> andPredicates = new ArrayList<>();

    if( person.getName() != null ) andPredicates.add(cb.equal(e.get("name"), person.getName()));
    if( /* similar code for the other properties */ ) /* ... */;

    predicates.add(cb.or(cb.and( andPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[andPredicates.size()]) )));
}
```

The code above assumes that not *all* properties of `Person` are `null`! If they might be, you have to guard against this accordingly!

Comment: oh I see.... Thanks! I will test this out and update the question with the results.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. This gives me a much more versatile way to get my data from the DB, allowing me to be specific in some things while being very broad in others. Thanks!!